# How do I set a button as always pressed? (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have a bar in my app with 2 buttons side by side.  One button represents the page the user is currently on and the other redirects the user to another page with the same button bar.  What I want is for the button that represents the page the user is currently on to look like it is pressed (i.e. the color it would be if it is pressed).  I already have it set so it can't be clicked.  Is there a setting or attribute or do I HAVE to create my own selector (because I don't really understand how to implement that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have never tried this but

```
button.setPressed(true)
```

should work.
Edit: You can also add

```
button.setClickable(false)
```

Edit: This does work but the order is important. Use this

```
    btn.setClickable(false);
    btn.setPressed(true);
```

Comment: If I just have setClickable(false) it works, but I need it to be the color it would be if pressed.  When I try setPressed(true) it stays pressed, but when I click it it changes back to normal.  I tried using both, but I get the same result as when I just use setPressed.

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't work.  For some reason the button is still allowing me to click it.  I tried taking away the setPressed() and just having setClickable(), but now that doesn't work for some reason :(.  I'm using eclipse.  I don't know if that would have anything to do with it.  Also for reference, I have been placing this code in my onCreate() method in my activity.

Comment: your answer works perfectly.  For some reason it works on one page but not the other, so it must be something i accidentally did :\.  Thanks!